# Twitter Bootstrap SelectPicker onchange function not being called

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have a simple select list

```
<select id="themes" class="selectpicker">
    <option selected>mkl-ambiance</option>
    <option>default</option>
    <option>ambiance</option>
    <option>blackboard</option>
</select>
```

and a small snippit of jquery

```
   $("#themes").change(function() {
        var theme = $("#themes").val();
        editor.setOption("theme", theme);
    });
```

if I remove `class="selectpicker"` from the select the call back works as expected. 
I even added `onchange="doMyFunction` and changing `$("#themes").change(function() {` to  `function doMyFunction() {` and that still didn't work. Is there some bootstrap magic I'm missing to get this to work properly?

Comment: yeah, sorry that was my typo here. It's .change on the page but still no callback

Comment: I think I got it. apparently it was getting called but was failing to get a valid value from the select. I edited the following; var theme = $("#theme").val() to var theme = #(theme :selected").text() and it started working.

Answer (score 3):

This is because Selectpicker generates `<ul>` and `<li>` tags and keeps the `<select>` and `<option>` aside. It adds 'rel' attribute to each `<li>` element for you to know which option is selected in relation to the selected `<li>`.

Anyways, you should either use an official onChange event from the Selectpicker plugin, or do something like the following:

```
$('ul.dropdown-menu.selectpicker li').on('click', function () {
    var selectedValue = $($('select.selectpicker option')[$(this).attr('rel')]).val();
});
```